# What is $SO(n+1)/O(n)$ as a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, quotient-spaces

> Consider $SO(n),O(n)$ as topological groups. Find out $SO(n+1)/O(n)$ as a topological space.

My attempt:

Observed the inclusion : $O(n) \hookrightarrow{} SO(n+1)$ by,
$$A \mapsto\begin{bmatrix} det(A) &0 \\ 0 &A\end{bmatrix}$$ i.e. basically, $$A \mapsto\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 &A\end{bmatrix} \text{ or } A \mapsto\begin{bmatrix} -1 &0 \\ 0 &A\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we know that $SO(n+1)$ acts transitively on $S^n$ and moreover, $$SO(n+1)\text{ / }SO(n) \cong S^n \tag{*}.$$

I was trying to imitate the proof of $(*)$, but could not proceed.

Intuitively, it seems to me that $SO(n+1) \text{ / } O(n) \cong \Bbb RP^n$ , but I really don't have any proof or anything,just intuition.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: If we call the inclusion $\iota$, then for odd $n$, $\iota(O_-(n)) = -I_{n + 1} \cdot \iota(SO(n))$, so $SO(n + 1) / O(n) = (SO(n + 1) / SO(n)) / \{\pm I_{n + 1}\} = S^n / \{\pm I_{n + 1}\} = \Bbb R \Bbb P^n$.

Comment: @Travis would you please consider writing an answer

Comment: I deliberately wrote a comment because the above case only covers the case $n$ odd, but there's an easy argument that is indifferent to parity: The group $SO(n + 1)$ acts transitively on the space $\Bbb R \Bbb P^n$ of lines in $\Bbb R^{n  + 1}$, and $\iota(O(n))$ is precisely the stabilizer of the line spanned by the first standard basis element, so we may identify $SO(n + 1) / \iota(O(n))$ with $\Bbb R \Bbb P^n$. One can likewise identify $SO(n + 1) / \iota(SO(n))$ with the space of rays from the origin in $\Bbb R^{n + 1}$, which we can identify with $\Bbb S^n$ as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that the quotient can be identified with $\Bbb R \Bbb P^n$.

**Hint** The usual action of $SO(n + 1)$ on $\Bbb R^{n + 1}$ is transitive and linear, so it descends to a transitive action on the space $\Bbb R \Bbb P^n$ of lines through the origin in $\Bbb R^{n + 1}$. Thus, if we fix an element $\ell \in \Bbb R \Bbb P^n$, we can identify $SO(n + 1) / H$, where $H < SO(n + 1)$ is the stabilizer in $SO(n + 1)$ of $\ell$.

> If we take $\ell$ to be the span $[e_0]$ of the first standard basis element, $g \in SO(n + 1)$ fixes $\ell$ iff it has the form $$\pmatrix{\ast & \ast \\ 0 & \ast},$$ and the condition $g \in SO(n + 1)$ implies that any such $g$ has the form $$\pmatrix{\det A & 0 \\ 0 & A}, \qquad A \in O(n); $$ conversely, any matrix of that form is in $H$.